# Is it possible build such query to Parse.com using Rest API

Tags: rest, parse-platform, include

I have DB structure that was made before me and it's not preferred change it.
To include pointer object to main query we use **'include'**.
In my query I need twice query **_User** collection:

```
my_main_query
-> userId
-> some_collection -> another_collection -> userId
```

(in this query I get different users information, like one asked something and another, who answered).

In both collections used same name **userId** as pointer to **_User** collection.

When I build RestAPI call, i tried:

```
'include' => 'userId, some_collection, another_collection, userID'
```

or

```
'include' => 'userId, some_collection.another_collection.userID'
```

and

```
'include' => 'some_collection.another_collection.userID, userId'
```

But each time my query returns only one user information, not both in same query.

Maybe somebody faced with this problem and could help build such query. Renaming fields not preferred.

Comment: There are 2 collection, and you want to get objects from these 2 collection in on query? Query can only target only one url(one collection)

Answer (score 0):

regarding collection of pointers to users in a column type array that looks like:

```
 [{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"$id1"}, {"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"$id2"}...]
```

You can use RestApi to POST or PUT the above to a property type ARRAY. Call it myclass.followingUsrs.

you can do a rest query include such as

```
&include=followingUsrs
```

Then with separate property with type=pointer<_User> and name myclass.createdBy you fill it with POST or PUT of

```
"createdBy":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"$id"}
```

and you can query/include it with

```
  include=createdBy
```

Note that in a single query, you can request an "include" more than one of these types of pointer-properties by just supplying a [comma seperated list](https://www.parse.com/questions/include-more-than-one-in-rest-api)

--EDIT-- no whitespace

```
include=createdBy,followingUsrs
```

The above in a rest query will inline the full createdBy._User as well as inlining EACH user pointer in the Array=followingUsrs.

Comment: Thanks Robert, it's interest solution and it could be implemented in some cases. But your answer contains small thing that making it wrong :) (check please my answer).

Comment: answer is changed per comment from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

After number of tests I was found solution and it was, as usual very simple:
This will not work:

```
'include' => 'userId, some_collection.another_collection.userId'
```

But this one will work:

```
'include' => 'userId,some_collection.another_collection.userId'
```

just WHITESPACE...